# Who creates /etc/resolv.conf file under docker in Alpinelinux

Tags: linux, networking, docker, alpine-linux, resolv.conf

I prepared my Alpinelinux docker image with a proper `/etc/resolv.conf` file but when I start it I found its content get changed, to:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 2607:fe...
```

I searched and listed all my Alpinelinux packages and I'm sure nothing close to `systemd` or `resolved` is installed.

So is `/etc/resolv.conf` file created by docker host?

Anyway, this is the actual reason I'm asking the question --

```
% cp /etc/resolv.conf.good /etc/resolv.conf
cp: can't create '/etc/resolv.conf': File exists

% ls /etc/resolv.conf -l
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           615 May  5 12:45 /etc/resolv.conf
```

I.e., why is `/etc/resolv.conf` file so special that even `cp` would fail?
Never see that before. Hints?

Comment: Docker [inherits](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services) `/etc/resolv.conf` from host to all containers that doesn't have custom DNS configurations. Try to check your host's `/etc/resolv.conf` and compare it to your container's `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: No, they are different. I checked before asked.